# Blocking '0000-00-00' from MySQL Date Fields

Tags: mysql, datetime, date, data-cleaning

I have a database where old code likes to insert '0000-00-00' in Date and DateTime columns instead of a real date. So I have the following two questions:

1. Is there anything that I could do on the db level to block this? I know that I can set a column to be not-null, but that does not seem to be blocking these zero values.
2. What is the best way to detect the existing zero values in date fields? I have about a hundred tables with 2-3 date columns each and I don't want to query them individually.

**Followup:**

The default is already set to null. A long time ago, the default was '0000-00-00'. Some code still explicitly places '0000-00-00'. I would prefer to force that code to throw an error so I could isolate and remove it.

Comment: I can't believe MySQL doesn't support CHECK constraints. I was going to post it as an answer, it's not an option. More and more, I understand the MySQL hate. Never used it myself.

Answer (score 15):

> Is there anything that I could do on the db level to block this?

Yes, enable the NO_ZERO_DATE mode:

```
SET sql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_DATE';
```

[The behaviour is documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html).  Additionally, you might want to also set the mode to include NO_ZERO_IN_DATE...

Also make sure the sql_mode includes either STRICT_ALL_TABLES or STRICT_TRANS_TABLES; without these NO_ZERO_IN_DATE only give a warning, but insert still succeeds.

> What is the best way to detect the existing zero values in date fields? I have about a hundred tables with 2-3 date columns each and I don't want to query them individually.

Separate columns means they have to be checked individually--nothing you can do about that.

Comment: (this only works when inserting new data - not much help if you've got a database full of bad data)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can't easily fix the data and "SET sql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_DATE';", you could create a view on the table...

```
CREATE VIEW filter AS
SELECT other_column, 
CASE 
  WHEN realtable.dodgy_date = 0 THEN NULL 
  ELSE realtable.dodgy_date
END AS dodgy_date
FROM realtable;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SET SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'NO_ZERO_DATE',''));   
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',''));
```

Just run above queries on database. It will solve the issue permanently.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't matter what date goes in there (ie as long as it's non-zero) you can change the column definition to use NOW() as the default. Probably not an ideal solution, but it does satisfy the criteria :
1) Not-null
2) Non-zero
I'm actually really not proud of that suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You could make the columns nullable and have `NULL` as the default value, but it sounds like you already have that and it's not working. ALTHOUGH... it could be the tool you're using to display the data doesn't like displaying `NULL` dates... what tool are you using? Or is the '0000-00-00' showing up in data retreived by code?

You could set a default value that is non-null and also easily recognizable as a default such as `1900-01-01` (assuming you don't normally deal with dates that are close to this date).

Answer (score 0):

A [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) can be used to enforce values for columns.

Answer (score 0):

set the timestamp by default is maybe an option for you, use table change statement for that:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CHANGE date_update timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE()
```

[MySQL CURRENT_DATE() documentation at w3c resource](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-current_date-function.php)

To remove Zero Dates and replace them by e.g. the current date do this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET date_update = CURRENT_DATE() where date_update = "0000-00-00"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the trigger I use:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER bad_date BEFORE INSERT ON some_table
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            IF NEW.the_date='0000-00-00' THEN 
                SET NEW.the_date= CURDATE();
            END IF;
        END;//
```

If updates are a concern, add a separate trigger (BEFORE UPDATE) to do the same thing.