# MySQL Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Tags: mysql

I've recently taken over an old project that was created 10 years ago. It uses MySQL 5.1.

Among other things, I need to change the default character set from latin1 to utf8.

As an example, I have tables such as this:

```
  CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `first_name` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `username` varchar(127) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(127) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
    `pass` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
    `active` char(1) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
    `created` datetime NOT NULL,
    `last_login` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `author` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT 'N',
    `locked_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `ripple_token` varchar(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `ripple_token_expires` datetime DEFAULT '2014-10-31 08:03:55',
    `authentication_token` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `index_users_on_reset_password_token` (`reset_password_token`),
    UNIQUE KEY `index_users_on_confirmation_token` (`confirmation_token`),
    UNIQUE KEY `index_users_on_unlock_token` (`unlock_token`),
    KEY `users_active` (`active`),
    KEY `users_username` (`username`),
    KEY `index_users_on_email` (`email`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1677 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 CHECKSUM=1 DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

I set up my own Mac to work on this. Without thinking too much about it, I ran "brew install mysql" which installed MySQL 5.7. So I have some version conflicts.

I downloaded a copy of this database and imported it.

If I try to run a query like this:

```
  ALTER TABLE users MODIFY first_name varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci    NOT NULL
```

I get this error:

```
  ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'created' at row 1
```

I thought I could fix this with:

```
  ALTER TABLE users MODIFY created datetime  NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00';
  Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
  Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

but I get:

```
  ALTER TABLE users MODIFY first_name varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci    NOT NULL ;
  ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'created' at row 1
```

Do I have to update every value?

Comment: The accepted answer is outdated please see @TariqKhan's answer below for mysql 8.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My suggestion if it is the case that the table is empty or not very very big is to export the create statements as a .sql file, rewrite them as you wish. Also do the same if you have any existing data, i.e. export insert statements (I recommend doing this in a separate file as the create statements). Finally, drop the table and execute first create statement and then inserts.

You can use for that either `mysqldump` command, included in your MySQL installation or you can also install MySQL Workbench, which is a free graphical tool that includes also this option in a very customisable way without having to look for specific command options.

Comment: Lucia Pasarin, I like your idea very much, but won't the data get truncated? Does some UTF8 data take up more bytes than latin1? If something previously fit in varchar 255, perhaps now it won't? Should I, perhaps, change all varchars to "text" fields?

Comment: Yes, you are right. That could happen since latin1 uses 1 byte per char, whereas utf8 uses at most 4 bytes per char (depending on the version of MySQL and on the type of utf8 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html). Therefore, you don't necessarily need TEXT type. I would assume that x4 your previously existing sizes should work.

Comment: This is the database equivalent of reformatting your hard drive when you want to delete a file.  It's safe to say this solution is not acceptable in a production environment.

Comment: Answer in comment below is the best UPDATE users SET created = NULL WHERE created=0;

Answer (score 300):

I wasn't able to do this:

```
UPDATE users SET created = NULL WHERE created = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

(on MySQL 5.7.13).

I kept getting the `Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'` error.

Strangely, this worked: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE created = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'`. I have no idea why the former fails and the latter works... maybe a MySQL bug?

At any case, this UPDATE query worked:

```
UPDATE users SET created = NULL WHERE CAST(created AS CHAR(20)) = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Comment: I had the same problem, but setting the last part to just 0 fixed it for me like this: `UPDATE users SET created = NULL WHERE created = '0'`

Comment: SELECT * FROM `entity` WHERE createdAt = "0000-00-00 00:00:00"  work fine, but with an updated fail !   I had the same problem. Fix it with solution of @obe CAST(created AS CHAR(20)) ... I think that it is a bug.

Comment: For me it worked like `UPDATE users SET created = NULL WHERE created=0` (without ' around zero)

Comment: For replacing a "0000-00-00" date only without timestamp, I used CHAR(11)

Comment: Damn, I've only ever seen '0000-00-00 00:00:00' as a filler for "null" datetime columns. Before I go and change the 32 columns I have like this, is it ANSI standard to have null or an actual date (start of epoch)?

Comment: That is pure genius. Why is this not the accepted answer?
For date only without timestamp the minimum value is 1000-01-01. Consider using this as the default value for every date attribute you intent to leave empty or with 0000-00-00 value.

Comment: KIR's answer above - `UPDATE users SET created = NULL WHERE created=0` - worked like a charm for me.  This is the simplest answer and should be marked as such!   See also comments below re `NO_ZERO_DATE` and `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`.

Comment: Just to add a little more info, using `WHERE YEAR(created) = "0000"` also works.

Comment: CAST(created AS CHAR(20)) this worked for me like a charm

Answer (score 217):

Changing the default value for a column with an `ALTER TABLE` statement, e.g.

```
 ALTER TABLE users MODIFY created datetime  NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-02'
```

... doesn't change any values that are already stored. The "default" value applies to rows that are inserted, and for which a value is not supplied for the column.

---

As to why you are encountering the error, it's likely that the `sql_mode` setting for your session includes **`NO_ZERO_DATE`**.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date

When you did the "import", the SQL statements that did the INSERT into that table were run in a session that allowed for zero dates.

To see the sql_mode setting:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode' ;
```

-or-

```
SELECT @@sql_mode ;
```

As far as how to "fix" the current problem, so that the error won't be thrown when you run the `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Several options:

1) change the `sql_mode` to allow zero dates, by removing `NO_ZERO_DATE` and `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`. The change can be applied in the my.cnf file, so after a restart of MySQL Server, `sql_mode` variable will be initialized to the setting in my.cnf.

For a temporary change, we can modify the setting with a single session, without requiring a global change.

```
-- save current setting of sql_mode
SET @old_sql_mode := @@sql_mode ;

-- derive a new value by removing NO_ZERO_DATE and NO_ZERO_IN_DATE
SET @new_sql_mode := @old_sql_mode ;
SET @new_sql_mode := TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT(',',@new_sql_mode,','),',NO_ZERO_DATE,'  ,','));
SET @new_sql_mode := TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT(',',@new_sql_mode,','),',NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,',','));
SET @@sql_mode := @new_sql_mode ;

-- perform the operation that errors due to "zero dates"

-- when we are done with required operations, we can revert back
-- to the original sql_mode setting, from the value we saved
SET @@sql_mode := @old_sql_mode ;
```

2) change the `created` column to allow NULL values, and update the existing rows to change the zero dates to null values

3) update the existing rows to change the zero dates to a valid date

---

We don't need to run individual statements to update each row. We can update all of the rows in one fell swoop (assuming it's a reasonably sized table. For a larger table, to avoid humongous rollback/undo generation, we can perform the operation in reasonably sized chunks.)

In the question, the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value shown for the table definition assures us that the number of rows is not excessive.

If we've already changed the `created` column to allow for `NULL` values, we can do something like this:

```
UPDATE  `users` SET `created` = NULL WHERE `created` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Or, we can set those to a valid date, e.g. January 2, 1970

```
UPDATE  `users` SET `created` = '1970-01-02' WHERE `created` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

(Note that a datetime value of midnight Jan 1, 1970 (`'1970-01-01 00:00:00'`) *is* a "zero date". That will be evaluated to be `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`

Comment: yes, this worked for me. I searched for sql-mode in my.ini file and removed NO_ZERO_IN_DATE and NO_ZERO_DATE . then restarted the service. thank you spencer7593 !

Comment: Set NO_ZERO_DATE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891896/blocking-0000-00-00-from-mysql-date-fields

Comment: When I do #2 "change the created column to allow NULL values", it won't let me because the column values still produce the error.  Quite stuck.

Comment: @MikeWeir:  presumably "**won't let me**" means that an error is returned when a SQL statement is executed. That's likely due to the setting of `sql_mode`. More recent versions of MySQL have default settings of `sql_mode` that are more strict that previous versions. Reference for 8.0 here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html   see `NO_ZERO_DATE`, `ALLOW_INVALID_DATE`, et al. note that some are included in STRICT mode e.g. `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` and other combo modes. To workaround the restrictions, temporarily modify sql_mode for the session,

Comment: @spencer7593 for sure.  I didn't feel like that option either was best.  I took your advice of setting a very old date value (1970) and my system will just ignore it.  Thanks for all your detail.

Comment: I would argue there are almost zero instances where a date field should be NOT NULL and also default to '1970-01-02'. Is there really an instance where you want to record a date for something, and by default that date is '1970-01-02'? If you don't yet have a valid value for a date then it should be NULL until you have an actual date. This also makes querieing more sensable. e.g. `where occurence is null` vs something less obvious like `where occurence = '1970-01-02'`.

Comment: @DavidBaucum:  you could make a similar argument for a DATE value of `'0000-00-00'`. You can make an argument for/against the `NO_ZERO_DATE` and `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` in sql_mode. But that wasn't the question that was asked. OP asked about how to get the ALTER TABLE statement to execute. This answer described a scenario that allowed the "zero" dates to be loaded, and one possible approach as a workaround, replacing the zero dates with a valid date. We could set the column to NULL if it weren't for the NOT NULL constraint; to remove it we have to workaround the invalid zero date, w/sql_mode or upd

Comment: @DavidBaucum: option 2) in this answer suggests allowing NULL values for the column; we can temporarily adjust `sql_mode` to allow the zero dates , and then do an UPDATE to assign NULL in place of 0000-00-00 ...

Comment: @spencer7593 Agree completely.

Comment: >  ALTER TABLE users MODIFY created datetime  NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-02'
If my `created` column was an index as well - wouldn't this remove the index?

Comment: @Mikey  No. Altering a column to change the default value would not remove any index from the table.  In the more general case, for columns that are included in an index, we could encounter errors for some column alterations, for example, if increasing the maximum size (length) for a character column would violate the maximum length allowed for an index. But we would expect MySQL to return an error, not remove an index.

Comment: Please note, that since MySQL 8.0 you also need to add `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES`

Answer (score 190):

I got it fixed by doing this before the query

```
SET SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
```

Comment: This is the only answer. Used as: --init-command='SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;SET SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES'

Comment: This is needed in MySQL 8.0, also add this and remove `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` and `NO_ZERO_DATE` from sql mode in the corresponding file inside `/etc/mysql/conf.d/`

Comment: I would like to click on UP 10 more times!

Comment: YES! Lifesaving answer. I used it in this way:
`mysql -u username -p database --init-command="SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;SET SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';" < filename.sql`

Comment: do not do `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0`! You don't need that to fix the date problem and you really shouldn't do it unless you know what you're doing. Disabling foreign keys will lead to data integrity errors

Comment: To all MySQL Newbies: This command overwrites your current SQL_MODE Settings and can bring you in some serious trouble,

Answer (score 58):

According to [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html):

> The default SQL mode in MySQL 5.7 includes these modes: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, and NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION.

Since `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is not a valid `DATETIME` value, your database is broken. That is why MySQL 5.7 – which comes with `NO_ZERO_DATE` mode enabled by default – outputs an error when you try to perform a write operation.

You can fix your table updating all invalid values to any other valid one, like `NULL`:

```
UPDATE users SET created = NULL WHERE created < '0000-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Also, to avoid this problem, I recomend you always set current time as default value for your `created`-like fields, so they get automatically filled on `INSERT`. Just do:

```
ALTER TABLE users
ALTER created SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 34):

Instead of

```
UPDATE your_table SET your_column = new_valid_value where your_column = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

Use

```
UPDATE your_table SET your_column = new_valid_value where your_column = 0;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. This one should be marked as answer in my opinion. Thanks!

Comment: This saved my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

Here what my solution *PhpMyAdmin / Fedora 29 /  MySQL 8.0* (for example):

`set sql_mode='SOMETHING';` **doesn't work**, command call successful but nothing was change.

`set GLOBAL sql_mode='SOMETHING';` **change global configuration** permanent change.

`set SESSION sql_mode='SOMETHING';` **change session configuration** SESSION variable affects only the current client.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html

So I do this :

- Get SQL_MODE : `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';`
- Result : 
  `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`
- Remove on the result : `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE`
- Set new configuration : `set GLOBAL SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'`

You can remove or add other mode in the same way.

This is helpful to change global for using and testing frameworks or sql_mode must be specified in each file or bunch of queries.

Adapted from a question ask here : [how-can-i-disable-mysql-strict-mode](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/17070/how-can-i-disable-mysql-strict-mode)

Example : install latest Joomla 4.0-alpha content.

**Edit:**
In PhpMyadmin, if you have the control of the server, you can change the `sql_mode` (and all others parameters) directly in `Plus > Variables > sql_mode`

Comment: plus 1 Thanks. if this is being reset when restart  Ubuntu Machine, add this in /etc/mysql/conf.d

Answer (score 14):

I found the solution at https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000666509-How-to-change-the-SQL-mode-in-MySQL. I had this:

```
mysql> show variables like 'sql_mode';
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                                                                                                                     |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sql_mode      | ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

Notice the `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE` in the results above. I removed that by doing this:

```
mysql> SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Then I had this:

```
mysql> show variables like 'sql_mode';
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                                                                                        |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sql_mode      | ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

After doing that, I could use `ALTER TABLE` successfully and alter my tables.

Comment: in the fly:  SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE', ''));   and same with second option

Comment: Also add ALLOW_INVALID_DATES

Answer (score 10):

```
SET sql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_DATE';
UPDATE `news` SET `d_stop`='2038-01-01 00:00:00' WHERE `d_stop`='0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Comment: This answer would be improved with discussion of why this solves the issue.

Comment: is this affects the datetime storage.? or cause any problems

Answer (score 10):

Check

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

if you see 'ZERO_DATE' stuff in there, try

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'NO_ZERO_DATE',''));   
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',''));
```

Log out and back in again to your client (this is strange) and try again

Answer (score 10):

This issue is happening because MYSQL 5.7 introduced default modes like

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode global, @@SESSION.sql_mode session;
=> ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION | ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Among the default modes, there is a mode `NO_ZERO_DATE` which prevents you to put the value  `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in the datetime column.

Temporary fix would be removing the mode `NO_ZERO_DATE`/`NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` from the default modes and keeping the other modes as it is.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

But once you restart your mysql server, all your temporary settings will be gone and the default modes will be enabled again. To fix this on restart, change the default modes in my.cnf file on your machine.

Refer the docs :- [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#:~:text=To%20set%20the%20SQL%20mode,ini%20(Windows)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#:%7E:text=To%20set%20the%20SQL%20mode,ini%20(Windows)).

My personal opinion :- The right developmental practice would be putting a right datetime value in the column instead of `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. So that you don't have to worry about the SQL modes.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I did to solve my problem. I tested in local **MySQL 5.7 ubuntu 18.04.**

```
set global sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";
```

Before running this query globally I added a cnf file in  ***/etc/mysql/conf.d*** directory. The cnf file name is ***mysql.cnf*** and codes

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Then I restart mysql

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Hope this can help someone.

Comment: This solution is working until I restart the MySQL server. Even after the restart the value `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` is in all columns of `SELECT @@global.sql_mode, @@session.sql_mode, @@sql_mode;` but still I get an error for the invalid datetime `0000-00-00 00:00:00` until I execute the first query again `set global sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";` Any ideas?

Comment: The solution in my case was to remove `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE` in your version of the my.ini line defining the `sql_mode`.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the type of **created** field from `datetime` to `varchar(255)`, then you can set (update) all records that have the value `"0000-00-00 00:00:00"` to `NULL`.

Now, you can do your queries without error.
After you finished, you can alter the type of the field **created** to `datetime`.

Answer (score 4):

I have this error as well after upgrading MySQL from 5.6 to 5.7

**I figured out that the best solution for me was to combine some of the solutions here and make something of it that worked with the minimum of input.**

I use MyPHPAdmin for the simplicity of sending the queries through the interface because then I can check the structure and all that easily. You might use ssh directly or some other interface. The method should be similar or same anyway.

...

**1.**

**First check out the actual error when trying to repair the db:**

> joomla.jos_menu Note     : TIME/TIMESTAMP/DATETIME columns of old format have been upgraded to the new format.
>
> Warning  : Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'checked_out_time' at row 1
>
> Error    : Invalid default value for 'checked_out_time'
>
> status  : Operation failed

This tells me the column checked_out_time in the table jos_menu needs to have all bad dates fixed as well as the "default" changed.

...

**2.**

**I run the SQL query based on the info in the error message:**

```
UPDATE jos_menu SET checked_out_time = '1970-01-01 08:00:00' WHERE checked_out_time = 0
```

If you get an error you can use the below query instead that seems to always work:

```
UPDATE jos_menu SET checked_out_time = '1970-01-01 08:00:00' WHERE CAST(checked_out_time AS CHAR(20)) = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

...

**3.**

**Then once that is done I run the second SQL query:**

```
ALTER TABLE `jos_menu` CHANGE `checked_out_time` `checked_out_time` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Or in the case it is a date that has to be NULL

```
ALTER TABLE `jos_menu` CHANGE `checked_out_time` `checked_out_time` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

...

**If I run repair database now I get:**

joomla.jos_menu               OK

...

Works just fine :)

Answer (score 3):

Make the sql mode non strict

if using laravel go to config->database,  the go to mysql settings and make the strict mode false

Comment: Can I do this in myphpadmin?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is just a interface to use the actual mysql server, it doesn't matter which interface you are using mysql commands won't change with the interface.

Try this command (set sql_mode='';) or this (set global sql_mode='';) to turn it off.

Comment: yeah I found all thats needed to turn off strict mode is adding sql_mode= (and nothing after it), by bottom of my.cnf

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem but in my case some line had the value NULL.

so first I update the table:

```
update `my_table`set modified = '1000-01-01 00:00:00' WHERE modified is null
```

problem solved, at least in my case.

Answer (score 3):

For Symfony users: Add a default to your orm column as follows:

```
/**
 * @var DateTime $updatedAt
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"default" : "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
 */
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried

`SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';`

and, restart

`sudo service mysql restart`

which works for me

Answer (score 2):

I also got

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime
>   value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column

error info

Fix this by changing   `0000-00-00 00:00:00`  to  `1970-01-01 08:00:00`

`1970-01-01 08:00:00`  unix timestamp is 0

Comment: the problem is OP can't change the date because error. I guess it's error from `NO_ZERO_DATE `

Answer (score 2):

My solution

```
SET sql_mode='';
UPDATE tnx_k2_items
SET created_by = 790
, modified = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
, modified_by = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is incredibly ugly, but it also fixed the problem quickly for me. Your table needs a unique key which you will use to fix the tainted columns. In this example, the primary key is called 'id' and the broken timestamp column is called 'BadColumn'.

1. Select the IDs of the tainted columns.

   `select id from table where BadColumn='0000-00-00 00:00:00'`
2. Collect the IDs into a comma-delimited string. Example: `1, 22, 33`. I used an external wrapper for this (a Perl script) to quickly spit them all out.
3. Use your list of IDs to update the old columns with a valid date (1971 through 2038).

   `update table set BadColumn='2000-01-01 00:00:00' where id in (1, 22, 33)`

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the answers, I tried many of them with no change. I still get the error.

I researched it for a bit and found one that actually worked; for me anyway. But if it worked for me, it'll most likely work for everyone. Cause I never find the answers! lol

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, But I have used other Linux OS's like Fedora, Straight forward Linux, XAMPP, yadda. And this file seemed to be the same on all of them. I'm also using MySQL version 5.7.37-0.

On Ubuntu, I go to `/etc/mysql/`. In there, you have several conf files, but the one you want is `my.cnf`.

In `my.cnf`, you'll have a section labelled `[mysqld]`. Just below that (I put it before anything else), you'll enter the following:

```
sql_mode="ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Restart you MySQL Server and you should no longer receive that error.

That is the permanent solution. There is a temporary solution by entering the SQL Command--

`SET sql_mode="";`

--before your INSERT or UPDATE QUERY which contains such date or datetime values as ‘0000-00-00 00:00:00’, but that's a temporary solution that remains in your current session and you'll have to enter it again the next time you log in and have the same issue.

So, the permanent solution seems the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to set 0000-00-00 to your field without modifying mySQL configuration, then do following:

```
UPDATE your_table_name SET your_time_field=FROM_UNIXTIME(0) WHERE ...
```

FROM_UNIXTIME(0) doing the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you are entering the data manually you may consider removing the values and the zeros on the TIMESTAMP(6).000000 so that it becomes TIMESTAMP. That worked fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use current_timestamp() instead of '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like`:

```
like '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```