# MySQL convert DATETIME field 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000 to DATE

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have a table:

```
mysql> describe sk_users;
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| name                         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dst_date                     | datetime(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and data:

```
mysql> select name, dst_date from sk_users;
+------+----------------------------+
| name | dst_date                   |
+------+----------------------------+
| a    | 2023-02-28 00:00:00.000000 |
| b    | 2016-06-01 00:00:00.000000 |
| c    | 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000 |
+------+----------------------------+
```

I want to convert the 'dst_date' field from datetime to date, and when I'm trying to do it - I'm getting an error:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `sk_users` CHANGE `dst_date` `dst_date` DATE NULL;
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'dst_date' at row 3
```

I'm sorry, I can't figure out why I can't do this. Can you help me?

Thanks to **juergen**, I'm also tried to update the table to use NULL values instead, but it also gives me an error:

```
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'dst_date' at row 3
```

Comment: Why not use `null` instead of `0000-00-00`? Update the table first - set all those dates to `null`

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution!

Steps:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                                                                                                                     |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sql_mode      | ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can see `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE`. We need to temporary remove it.

```
mysql> SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

After that let's update our table to use NULL instead 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

```
update 
  sk_users
set 
  dst_date = NULL
where
  dst_date LIKE '0000-00-00%';
```

Then we can logout/login again (to restore our original sql_mode) and it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a value you should actually use `null`. So why not update the table first and then change the table structure?

```
update sk_users
set dst_date = NULL
where dst_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Comment: I'm tried to do this before:ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'dst_date' at row 1

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565128/mysql-incorrect-datetime-value-0000-00-00-000000

Answer (score 0):

Actually the convention is to null data that we don't have. So, instead filling the fields with '0000-00-00' just set it to NULL then you'll be able to change your table's structure more conveniently.

Here's a snippet how you can do it:

```
update 
  sk_users
set 
  dst_date = NULL
where
  dst_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a [Date() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date):

```
UPDATE sk_users set dst_date = date(dst_date);
```

It seems there's [a bug in mysql](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3331) forcing us to assign a sentinel to the date if it's null. So, the final answer becomes:

```
UPDATE sk_users set dst_date = now() where dst_date is null;UPDATE sk_users set dst_date = date(dst_date);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: mysql> update sk_users set dst_date = DATE(dst_date);
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00' for column 'dst_date' at row 3

Comment: mysql> UPDATE sk_users set dst_date = today where dst_date is null;UPDATE sk_users set dst_date = date(dst_date);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'today' in 'field list'
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00' for column 'dst_date' at row 3