# phpmyadmin won't allow changing structure due to a datetime column's #1067 error

Tags: mysql, datetime, phpmyadmin

There are two Datetime column in my table both having default value as "0000-00-00 00:00:00"[image]

When I was trying to change some structure(which is not related to either of these columns)of the table, an #1067 error shows up saying `invalid default value for 'product_date_added'.

**Question #1**
Why a datetime column's default value can't be "0000-00-00 00:00:00"?

Then I tried to change the default value of `product_date_added`, and here is what I got:
[image]

As shown in the picture, #1067 shows up for the other datetime column. And this goes vice versa, I am dumbfounding.

I tried this with other tables and they all have this issue: when trying to alter table structure, an #1067 error shows up for a datetime column whose default value is "0000-00-00 00:00:00".

I also tried to set the default value to a real datetime value from command shell, here is what I got:
[image]
As you can see, the 1067 error still shows up for the other column. Why these two column are affecting each other?

I also tried this:
and this:
[image]

**Question #2:**
How to solve this issue?

Comment: did you try updating that column with NULL (only rows with zero date time value) and then set default value null or changing the structure ?

Comment: Won't allow me to update it with null, says "please enter a valid date or time"

Comment: A way around to handle such problem is to choose a certain valid date time value eg. '2020-01-01 00:00:00' and update those rows with zero date value with that date hardcoded value, then you can set that column to default null and again check for that date value and update with null. Try it, if possible.

Comment: I tried setting default value to a real datetime, but it also won't allow me, showing the 1067 error for the other column too.

Comment: Run a sql query to update those zero date time values with dummy date value.

Comment: I've edited the question with an additional screenshot.@DeepanshSachdeva

Comment: `UPDATE table SET column = '2020-01-01 11:11:11' WHERE column = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'` run an update query, not alter table

Comment: Thanks. I tried please see the editted question for the screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565128/mysql-incorrect-datetime-value-0000-00-00-000000

Comment: @DeepanshSachdeva Thanks. I somehow get the answer from the question you post.

Answer (score 0):

1) The database won't accept a datetime value of "0000-00-00 00:00:00" because the the default `sql_mode` includes `NO_ZERO_DATE` and `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`

2) To solve the issue, the mode of mysql needs to be changed, which can be done in my.cnf file by adding

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = "modes"
```

where `modes` is a string. To get the `mode` string, one needs to get the original string by running "select @@sql_mode" and truncate the two modes string from it.