# Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table with 2M records and everything works fine until few hours ago. 
suddenly it throw error on a query that previously works fine for more than 1 year.
The problem is that inserting a correct dateTime like `2019-07-15 22:22:47` into a **timestamp** column return error:

> Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'created_at' at row 1

1- I did duplicated table structure and query works fine on duplicated table
2- I did run `yum update` today.
3- OS: CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
4- MySql: Server version: 8.0.16 MySQL Community Server - GPL

**Edit:**
 i have read other questions but its completely different, I've posted the answer

Comment: you have few old records in your table with incorrect datetime value of `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. You need to fix those. If you dont know the correct value for them; you can set them to `null`. Do: `SET sql_mode = ''; UPDATE your_table_name SET created_at = null WHERE created_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565128/mysql-incorrect-datetime-value-0000-00-00-000000)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya No, there is not any records with '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Comment: The question you had mentioned is completely a different situation, I'm inserting a new row with valid data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it, posting as answer that may help others

It seems that latest mysql update have some new roles added for comparing datetime values, however i think the error thrown is completely irrelevant.
i had a trigger on my table which check some parameter and also check if created_at column is equal to '0000-00-00 00:00:00' then change it to current_timestamp. part of trigger is

```
IF(NEW.created_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') THEN
    SET NEW.created_at = current_timestamp();
END IF
```

it just a simple compare and the result should be true or false, and should not throw the **zero date exception**.
however i removed this part and everything is up now

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit /etc/my.cnf and add line

sql-mode = ""

Save this file

2. Restart MySQL service

systemctl restart mysqld

3. Try your sql command,

example:

UPDATE TABLE test SET modified ='0000-00-00 00:00:00'