# Invalid datetime format: 1292 When using old dates

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, timestamp

I have people table and in this I have a field named birthday as timestamp.

When i insert date data like: `2017-05-19` its ok and no errors but when i want to insert some old dates like `1959-08-12` its says:

```
Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1959-08-12' for column 'birthday' at row 1
```

I am inserting the date like this:

```
Person::create([
...
  'birthday'   => date('Y-m-d' , strtotime($birthday)),
...
])
```

Also i try this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565128/mysql-incorrect-datetime-value-0000-00-00-000000) and remove the `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE` from `sql_mode` variable, but not working for me.

MySQL: 5.7.23
PHP: 7.2
Laravel: 6.5

Comment: Make sure the timezone on the server and MySQL is the same. If MySQL is not on the correct timezone you can update it with SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that the `birthday` column is of datatype [`TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) which has a range of 1970-01-01 00:00:01 to 2038-01-19 03:14:07, UTC.

```sql
create table t(birthday timestamp);
insert into t values ('1970-01-02');
/* Affected rows: 1  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.094 sec. */
insert into t values ('1969-12-30');
/* SQL Error (1292): Incorrect datetime value: '1969-12-30' for column 'birthday' at row 1 */
```

I would suggest using `DATE` datatype for birthdays because it does not contain time portion and has a larger range 1000-01-01 to 9999-12-31.

Answer (score 0):

the default format for date column in mysql is `Y-m-d` and for datetime is `Y-m-d H:i:s`. So change your date to this format and try again.

Or

Try this, parse the `date` using a Carbon object.

```
Person::create([
...
  'birthday'   => Carbon::parse($birthday),
...
])
```