# How do I setup Birthdates using Yii3 and its Cycle-ORM integration?

Tags: orm, date

**Preconditions**

1. mySql database **client_birthdate** field set as DATE and nullable if user does not enter date.
2. User inputs Client's Birthdate on __form textbox as a string in mySql format YYYY/MM/DD or not.
3. Yii3's ClientForm gets the string or empty string and converts to DATETIME so that Cycle Orm can process it.
4. Yii3's ClientService saves the date using Cycle's Client Entity's getter and setter methods and annotations.
5. [Php 7.4.9](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67630216/edit)
6. Typed property. Previously php allowed this variable declaration below a class `public $var;` now inserting typed property between public and $var ie `public ?string $var = ''` excludes other types. Question mark before type allows for null value input. So only two alternatives.
7. [Understanding mySql's '0000-00-00' for non date input.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565128/mysql-incorrect-datetime-value-0000-00-00-000000)
8. [Download fork of https://github.com/yiisoft/yii-demo](https://github.com/rossaddison/yii-invoice)

**dateHelper.php (adapted from Invoiceplane)**

```
/**
  * @return string|null
*/
public function date_from_mysql($date, $s)
{
       //if previous input was not a date mySql would have input '0000-00-00' 
       if ($date <> '0000-00-00') {
            //CYCLE converts all dates to DateTimeImmutable
             $date = DateTime::createFromImmutable($date);
            //$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
            //eg. $date->format('Ymd') 
            return $date->format($s->setting('date_format'));
        }
        return $date;
    }
    return '';
}
```

**__form.php caption**

```
 <div class="mb-3 form-group has-feedback">
        <label form-label for="client_birthdate"><?= $s->trans('birthdate'); ?></label>
       <?php
            $bdate = $body['client_birthdate'] ?? null;
            if ($bdate && $bdate != "0000-00-00") {
                //use the DateHelper
                $datehelper = new DateHelper();
                $bdate = $datehelper->date_from_mysql($bdate, false, $s);
            } else {
                $bdate = null;
            }
        ?>        
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="client_birthdate" id="client_birthdate" placeholder="1900/12/01"
                   class="form-control data-datepicker"
                   value="<?= Html::encode($bdate); ?>">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i>
        </span>
        </div>        
    </div>
```

**Entity/Client.php**

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Invoice\Entity;
use \DateTime;

/**
 * @Entity(
 *     repository="App\Invoice\Client\ClientRepository",
 *     mapper="App\Invoice\Client\ClientMapper",
 *     constrain="App\Invoice\Client\Scope\activeScope"
 * )
 * @Table(
 *     indexes={
 *         @Index(columns={"client_active"}),
 *     }
 * )
 */
class Client
{
    /**
     * @Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $client_birthdate = '';
    
    //CYCLE converts all date formats ie. DATE, DATETIME, to DateTimeImmutable so 
    work with DateTimeImmutable 
    
    public function __construct($client_birthdate = '')

    public function getClient_birthdate() : ?DateTimeImmutable  
    {
        if (isset($this->client_birthdate) && !empty($this->client_birthdate)){
            return $this->client_birthdate;            
        }
        if (empty($this->client_birthdate)){
            return $this->client_birthdate = null;
        }
    }    
    
    public function setClient_birthdate(?\DateTime $client_birthdate): void
    {
        $this->client_birthdate = $client_birthdate;
    }
```

**Client/ClientForm.php**

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Invoice\Client;

use Yiisoft\Form\FormModel;
use Yiisoft\Validator\Rule\Required;
use \DateTimeImmutable;
use \DateTime;

final class ClientForm extends FormModel {

private ?string $client_birthdate = null;

public function getClient_birthdate(): ?\DateTime
    {
        if (isset($this->client_birthdate) && !empty($this->client_birthdate)){
            return new DateTime($this->client_birthdate);            
        }
        if (empty($this->client_birthdate)){
            return $this->client_birthdate = null;
        } 
    }
```

**Client/ClientService**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Invoice\Client;

use App\Invoice\Entity\Client;
use App\User\User;

final class ClientService
{
private ClientRepository $repository;

    public function __construct(ClientRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;;
    }

    public function saveClient(User $user, Client $model, ClientForm $form): void
    {
    $model->setClient_birthdate($form->getClient_birthdate());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Things to look out for:**

1. Ensure _form 'id' and 'name' values eg. client_birthdate correspond to Entity @column and Database tables fields. ie Use field names consistently
   through Entity, Annotations. The ClientForm's getter method will receive data from the __form which is a string or null. The getter will convert this to a DATETIME or null so that CYCLE ORM (Spiral Framework) can process it.
2. Ensure initialization in Entity/Client.php instantiation area ie. BEFORE construct and IN construct.

**Tips**

1. Annotations above function are read by Cycle's annotations.
2. `use \DateTime;` before Annotations. Don't forget backslash to indicate DateTime is a php class not in current Namespace.
3. mySql type DATE in database and 'date' included in annotation below. ie. `* @Column(type="date", nullable=true)` otherwise Cycle will not be able to read it.
4. I have elected to use a simple untyped, nullable string.

.../Entity/Client.php

```
   public function getClient_birthdate() : ?\DateTimeImmutable
```

and

```
   public function setClient_birthdate(?\DateTime $client_birthdate): void
```

...src/Invoice/Entity/Client.php...

```
     /**
     * @Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $client_birthdate = '';
```

1. The value accepted from coalface __form uses a string so initialize ClientForm.php's `private ?string $client_birthdate = null` with a string
   not a DateTime function.
2. Question mark before ?\DateTime allows for null value. Use consistently in function declaration as well as seen below.

...src/Invoice/Client/ClientForm.php

```
    public function getClient_birthdate(): ?\DateTime
    {
        if (isset($this->client_birthdate) && !empty($this->client_birthdate)){
            return new DateTime($this->client_birthdate);            
        }
        if (empty($this->client_birthdate)){
            return $this->client_birthdate = null;
        } 
    }
```

The above code can be reduced to:

```
 public function getClient_birthdate() : ?\DateTime
    {
       // convert the input string on the form received by means of '$this->client_birthdate'
       // back into DateTime so that Cycle can deal with it and
       // save it in 'date' format in mysql behind the scenes
       return new DateTime($this->client_birthdate);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Update 21 September 2022](https://github.com/rossaddison/yii-invoice/blob/master/views/invoice/client/__form.php)

[Attributes are preferred now to annotations so above code has changed.](https://github.com/rossaddison/yii-invoice/blob/master/src/Invoice/Entity/Client.php)

Essentially, to represent a DateTimeImmutable on a form it must be presented with the ->format() command. A suitable style of date must be between the brackets eg. Y-m-d or even d-m-Y. To accomplish this, additional code may be used eg.

__form.php

```
<div class="mb-3 form-group has-feedback">
        <?php
           $bdate = $datehelper->get_or_set_with_style($body['client_birthdate']);
        ?>
        <label form-label for="client_birthdate"><?= $s->trans('birthdate') .' ('.$datehelper->display().')'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="client_birthdate" id="client_birthdate" placeholder="<?= ' ('.$datehelper->display().')';?>"
                   class="form-control input-sm datepicker" readonly                   
                   value="<?= null!== $bdate ? Html::encode($bdate instanceof \DateTimeImmutable ? $bdate->format($datehelper->style()) : $bdate) : null; ?>" role="presentation" autocomplete="off">
            <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i>
        </span>
        </div>        
    </div>
```

[Include the following datepicker jquery code in your layout file.](https://github.com/rossaddison/yii-invoice/blob/master/views/layout/invoice.php)

```
<?php
    // https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker
    $js1 = "$(function () {".
       '$(".form-control.input-sm.datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat:"'.$datehelper->datepicker_dateFormat()
                                                        .'", firstDay:'.$datehelper->datepicker_firstDay()
                                                        .', changeMonth: true'
                                                        .', changeYear: true'
                                                        .', yearRange: "-50:+10"'
                                                        .', clickInput: true'
                                                        .', constrainInput: false'
                                                        .', highlightWeek: true'
                                                        .' });'.
    '});';
    echo Html::script($js1)->type('module');
?>
```

[Here is reference to the styles.](https://github.com/rossaddison/yii-invoice/blob/master/src/Invoice/Helpers/DateHelper.php)

Answer (score 0):

Update 13 March 2024
Client Entity  client.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1); 

namespace App\Invoice\Entity;

use Cycle\Annotated\Annotation\Column;
use Cycle\Annotated\Annotation\Entity;
use Cycle\ORM\Entity\Behavior;
use \DateTime;
use \DateTimeImmutable; 

#[Entity(repository:\App\Invoice\Client\ClientRepository::class)]
#[Behavior\CreatedAt(field: 'client_date_created', column: 'client_date_created')]
#[Behavior\UpdatedAt(field: 'client_date_modified', column: 'client_date_modified')]    
class Client
 {
    #[Column(type: 'primary')]
    public ?int $id = null;
   
    #[Column(type: 'datetime')]
    private DateTimeImmutable $client_date_created;
    
    #[Column(type: 'datetime')]    
    private DateTimeImmutable $client_date_modified;
    
    #[Column(type:'date', nullable: true)]
    private mixed $client_birthdate;
     
    public function __construct(mixed $client_birthdate=null)
    {
        $this->client_birthdate = $client_birthdate;
        $this->client_date_created = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        $this->client_date_modified = new \DateTimeImmutable();
    }
    
    public function getClient_id(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    
    public function getClient_date_created(): DateTimeImmutable
    {
        /** @var DateTimeImmutable $this->client_date_created */
        return $this->client_date_created;
    }

    public function getClient_date_modified(): DateTimeImmutable
    {
        /** @var DateTimeImmutable $this->client_date_created */
        return $this->client_date_modified;
    }
    
    
    //cycle 
    public function getClient_birthdate() : DateTimeImmutable|string|null  
    {
        /** @var DateTimeImmutable|string|null $this->client_birthdate */
        return $this->client_birthdate;
    }    
    
    public function setClient_birthdate(?DateTime $client_birthdate): void
    {
        $this->client_birthdate = $client_birthdate;
    }
}
```

Form.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Invoice\Client;

use App\Invoice\Entity\Client;
use Yiisoft\FormModel\FormModel;
use Yiisoft\Validator\Rule\Required;
use Yiisoft\Validator\Rule\Integer;
use \DateTimeImmutable;

final class ClientForm extends FormModel
{
    private mixed $client_birthdate;
        
    public function __construct(Client $client) { 
        $this->client_birthdate = $client->getClient_birthdate();
    }
            
    public function getClient_birthdate() : string|null|DateTimeImmutable
    {
        /**
         * @var string|null|DateTimeImmutable $this->client_birthdate
         */
        return $this->client_birthdate;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return string
     *
     * @psalm-return ''
     */
    public function getFormName(): string
    {
      return '';
    }
}
```

service.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1); 

namespace App\Invoice\Client;

use App\Invoice\Entity\Client;
use App\Invoice\Helpers\DateHelper;

use App\Invoice\Setting\SettingRepository;

final class ClientService
{
    private ClientRepository $repository;

    public function __construct(ClientRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param Client $model
     * @param array $body
     * @param SettingRepository $s
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function saveClient(Client $model, array $body, SettingRepository $s): int|null
    {
        $datehelper = new DateHelper($s);
        $datetime = new \DateTime();
        isset($body['client_birthdate']) ? $model->setClient_birthdate($datetime::createFromFormat($datehelper->style(),(string)$body['client_birthdate'])) : '';
        $this->repository->save($model);
        return $model->getClient_id();
    }
    
}
```

form.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use Yiisoft\FormModel\Field;
use Yiisoft\Html\Html;
use Yiisoft\Html\Tag\Form;
use Yiisoft\Arrays\ArrayHelper;

/**
 * @var \Yiisoft\View\View $this
 * @var \Yiisoft\Router\UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator
 * @var string $csrf
 * @var string $action
 * @var string $title
 */
?>
<?= Html::openTag('div',['class'=>'container py-5 h-100']); ?>
<?= Html::openTag('div',['class'=>'row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100']); ?>
<?= Html::openTag('div',['class'=>'col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-xl-8']); ?>
<?= Html::openTag('div',['class'=>'card border border-dark shadow-2-strong rounded-3']); ?>
<?= Html::openTag('div',['class'=>'card-header']); ?>
<?= Html::openTag('h1',['class'=>'fw-normal h3 text-center']); ?>
<?= $translator->translate('i.client_form'); ?>
<?= Html::closeTag('h1'); ?>
<?=
    Form::tag()
    ->post($urlGenerator->generate(...$action))
    ->enctypeMultipartFormData()
    ->csrf($csrf)
    ->id('ClientForm')
    ->open()
?>
<?= 
    $alert; 
?>
<?= Field::errorSummary($form)
    ->errors($errors)
    ->header($translator->translate('invoice.client.error.summary'))
    ->onlyProperties(...['client_name', 'client_surname', 'client_email', 'client_age'])    
    ->onlyCommonErrors()
?>
<?= 
    Html::openTag('div', ['class'=> 'card']),
        Html::openTag('div', ['class'=>'card-header d-flex justify-content-between']), 
            $translator->translate('i.personal_information'),
            Html::openTag('div', ['class' => 'p-2']), 
                Field::checkbox($form, 'client_active')
                ->inputLabelAttributes(['class' => 'form-check-label'])    
                ->enclosedByLabel(true)
                ->inputClass('form-check-input')
                ->ariaDescribedBy($translator->translate('i.client_active')),
            Html::closeTag('div'),
        Html::closeTag('div'),
    Html::closeTag('div')    
?>
            <?php
                $bdate = $datehelper->get_or_set_with_style($form->getClient_birthdate() ?? new \DateTimeImmutable('now'));
                echo Field::text($form, 'client_birthdate')
                ->label($translator->translate('i.birthdate'), ['class' => 'form-label'])
                ->addInputAttributes([
                    'placeholder' => $translator->translate('i.birthdate'),
                    'class' => 'form-control input-sm datepicker',
                    'id' => 'client_birthdate',
                    'role' => 'presentation',
                    'autocomplete' => 'off'
                ])
                ->value($bdate)        
                ->required(false)
                ->readonly(true)        
                ->hint($translator->translate('invoice.hint.this.field.is.not.required')); 
            ?>    
                        <?= Html::closeTag('div'); ?>
                    <?= Html::closeTag('div'); ?>
                <?= Html::closeTag('div'); ?>
            <?= Html::closeTag('div'); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?= Html::closeTag('div'); ?>
    <?= Html::closeTag('div'); ?>
<?= Html::closeTag('div'); ?>
<?= $button::back_save(); ?>                
<?= Form::tag()->close(); ?>
<?= Html::closeTag('div'); ?>
<?= Html::closeTag('div'); ?>
<?= Html::closeTag('div'); ?>
<?= Html::closeTag('div'); ?>
<?= Html::closeTag('div'); ?>
```

```
/**
     * @param \DateTimeImmutable $datetimeimmutable
     * @return string
     */
    public function date_from_mysql(\DateTimeImmutable $datetimeimmutable): string {
        return DateTime::createFromImmutable($datetimeimmutable)->format($this->style());
    }

/**
     * @param mixed $input
     * @return string|false|null|DateTime
     */
    public function get_or_set_with_style(mixed $input): string|false|null|DateTime {
        /** @var mixed|null|\DateTimeImmutable $date */
        $date = $input ?? null;
        // Get with style
        if ($date instanceof \DateTimeImmutable) {
            $return_date = $this->date_from_mysql($date);
            // Set with style
        } elseif (null!==($date)) {
            $return_date = $this->datetime_zone_style((string) $date);
        } else {
            $return_date = null;
        }
        return $return_date;
    }
```

Comment: The above code has been psalm level 1 tested. It is useful to work with the mixed data type when working with dates because this can accomodate string, null, and DateTimeImmutable.This is particularly relevant to forms. DateTimeImmutables must be presented as a string so append ->format('Y-m-d') on the end.

Answer (score -1):

INVOICEPLANE SOLUTION
A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1525 Incorrect DATE value: '0000-00-00'                     fix error 58 El error se debe al modo sql, que puede ser un modo estricto
solution permanent to  Incorrect DATE value: '0000-00-00' change thsis data example > 1970-01-01
invoiceplane/application/modules/invoices/models/Mdl_invoices.php

or temporal solution mysql SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';

ubuntu 20.04
mysql 8

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31596614)