Alter table change column datatype, getting this Error Code: 1292
DESCRIBE mytable
id  bigint unsigned NO  PRI     auto_increment
**tournament_id bigint  YES**           
created_at  timestamp   YES         
updated_at  timestamp   YES 


ALTER TABLE mytable
    CHANGE tournament_id tournament_id  BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;

Error Received,
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'created_at' at row

When i try to change the datatype of a a particular column, getting an unexpected error showing error in an other column.Why i am getting this error, any help please.
Thanks

Which part of the error message is not clear to you?  You are trying to convert '0000-00-00 00:00:00' into BIGINT.

No, the column which i am trying to convert from BIGINT to BIGINT UNSIGNED. It is not a datetime datatype. ALTER TABLE mytable
CHANGE tournament_id tournament_id  BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;

Read this post and the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565128/mysql-incorrect-datetime-value-0000-00-00-000000

Here is the code which I tried and solved the issue:
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE mytable SET created_at = NULL WHERE created_at <= 0;
COMMIT;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;

ALTER TABLE mytable
    CHANGE tournament_id tournament_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NULL;

Now it's working fine.
Still not able to understand the scenario. However updating the value of the error thrown field works fine for altering the datatype of the other field.
MySQL version is 8.2.0 and I am running the database server in Windows. There can be a bug in MySQL side and not sure.
